# I got this "Error: Imported content is empty"

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml

I am trying to create a google sheet to combine some information. I want the sheet to pull information  h index of my friend

this is the code

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.uri?authorId=24385207400", " //*[@id='authorDetailsHindex']/div/div[2]/span")`

however the show me Error

> Imported content is empty.

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTXML only are able to get elements that have a well formed XML like structure. It looks that there is missing something missing on the path to the element that you want to get.

One alternative is to use the [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) from Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

`IMPORTHTML` or `IMPORTXML` won't work because **cookies are disabled** when you access a link through any of those functions. From what I know, Scopus needs cookies to be enabled in order to provide services.

**Google Apps Script** ([UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)) may be a way to get around the issue.

Here is a link for your reference - https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html